# How long does auto-bounty take?

Tags: support, bounties

I've seen [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67014/half-the-bounty-not-awarded-when-bounty-expires), in which the poster says he was never awarded the auto-bounty.  At some point since his question,  the bounty must have been awarded to him, because it's marked as such on the question in question ( couldn't resist `:)`

It looks like I should have been awarded the half-bounty [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316332/allow-user-to-change-layout-of-web-page/4605293#4605293), but I have not been as of yet. Can anyone provide illumination on this?

### edit: I've got the Bounty Now

But, for those searching this in the future, **How Long Does it Take?**

Comment: You *have* been awarded a bounty of 50 just [5 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4316332/revisions).

Comment: Right, @Arjan, check the edit.  But thanks for that link, I didn't know I could view other people's revisions.  cool!

Comment: You can always manually compose such link if you want to see the source, or simply click the date after "edited" once there are more revisions. Also nice: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4316332/timeline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounty is awarded hourly so it depends on the stop time vs the hour boundary.

Comment: It was awarded at 15:19:07Z. Lots of things to do then every hour?